# Django 1.4 with MySQL 5.6

Tags: django, mysql-5.6

In RDS I recently created a dump of my prod db and created a temp MySQL 5.6 db using the below commands:

```
mysqldump -u user --password=password -h host db_name | gzip -c > mysql.sql.gz
gunzip mysql.sql.gz
mysql -u user --password=password -h host db_name < mysql.sql
```

Everything worked fine. The one issue I'm noticing is that my app (Django 1.4) creates timestamps that are defined as per below:

```
`last_modified` timestamp NOT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```

Previously in MySQL 5.5 this was fine. But in 5.6, the `null` for the `last_modified` is not being interpreted as the current value. Is there anyway to handle this issue? ALL of my models have this issue....

**EDIT**

I updated the above field to:

```
alter table my_table modify last_modified timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

but when inserting, Django has a `null` for that field. Previously the null translated to the current timestamp, now it's just showing as `null` in the field. Is there a way to force MySQL to interpret `null` as the current timestamp?

Comment: Can you show the query that is being produced out of Django insert and the SQL that MySQL will show as a create statement for an example table?

Comment: The query had a `null` for timestamp fields. Which was not working since this was set to `not null`. My solution was a custom field where I provide a default time (current time)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From MySQL docs [Upgrading from MySQL 5.5 to 5.6](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html)

> TIMESTAMP columns declared as NOT NULL and without an explicit DEFAULT
>   clause are treated as having no default value. For inserted rows that
>   specify no explicit value for such a column, the result depends on the
>   SQL mode. If strict SQL mode is enabled, an error occurs. If strict
>   SQL mode is not enabled, the column is assigned the implicit default
>   of '0000-00-00 00:00:00' and a warning occurs. This is similar to how
>   MySQL treats other temporal types such as DATETIME.

So you should set the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as `DEFAULT` for this field, `ON UPDATE` isn't sufficient.